# How to declare more than one global variable in assembly?

Tags: assembly, printf, global-variables, x86-64

I am trying to convert the following code to assembly in x86 microprocessors in 64-bit mode.

The python code is as follows:

```
x = 0
y = 8
while x < 10:
    if x == y:
        break
    x += 1
    if x < 2:
        continue
    print(x)
```

Please note that I am working on an assembly code generator that takes as an input modern code and produces assembly code.

The code that it generated is as follows:

```
.data
.globl  x
.align  4
.type   x, @object
.size   x, 4
x:
    .long   0
.globl  y
.align  4
.type   y, @object
.size   y, 4
y:
    .long   8
.section .rodata
print_format_int:
    .string "%d\n"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

loop_start_0:
    pushq x(%rip)
    pushq $10
    popq %rax
    popq %rbx
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jge loop_end_1

if_start_2:
    pushq x(%rip)
    pushq y(%rip)
    popq %rax
    popq %rbx
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jne if_end_3
    jmp loop_end_1

if_end_3:
    movq x(%rip), %rax
    addq $1, %rax
    movq %rax, x(%rip)

if_start_4:
    pushq x(%rip)
    pushq $2
    popq %rax
    popq %rbx
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jge if_end_5
    jmp loop_start_0

if_end_5:
    movq x(%rip), %rsi
    leaq print_format_int(%rip), %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    jmp loop_start_0

loop_end_1:
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

I compile this code using `gcc file_name.s -g filename` and I run it simply by `./filename`.

Now the issue is that when I run nothing at all is printed. I do not get any warnings or errors, but nothing gets printed. I tried to remove the variable y from the program and remove the part where I compare x to y, and then the program works with its new logic. The assembly code after removing y is as follows:

```
.data
.globl  x
.align  4
.type   x, @object
.size   x, 4
x:
    .long   0

.section .rodata
print_format_int:
    .string "%d\n"
.text
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

loop_start_0:
    pushq x(%rip)
    pushq $10
    popq %rax
    popq %rbx
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jge loop_end_1

    movq x(%rip), %rax
    addq $1, %rax
    movq %rax, x(%rip)

if_start_4:
    pushq x(%rip)
    pushq $2
    popq %rax
    popq %rbx
    cmpq %rax, %rbx
    jge if_end_5
    jmp loop_start_0

if_end_5:
    movq x(%rip), %rsi
    leaq print_format_int(%rip), %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    jmp loop_start_0

loop_end_1:
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

I'm not so sure what the issue is as I am just a beginner in assembly. I suspect it has something to do with stack alignment but I am not able to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: That is how you declare more than one global variable.  You're might be over-aligning them (by 16 instead of 4 on some platforms where `.align` is `.p2align` rather than `.balign`.  Never use `.align`, use one of the two explicit ones; GAS treats it differently on different OSes.)  Their size is `4` but you're doing 8-byte loads/stores on them, so loads from `x` get `y<<32` as the high half.  (On platforms where `.align` is `.balign`, otherwise there's padding).

Comment: `pushq x(%rip)` / ... / `popq %rax` is a very inefficient way to write `mov x(%rip), %rax`.  And there's no `push/pop` way to load these 4-byte variables correctly like you can with `mov x(%rip), %eax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I replaced all my push/pop in comparison with mov (specifically movl) and it worked.

Comment: Sure, you can use an explicit size suffix even when an operand implies dword operand-size (`%eax` destination in this case).  Compilers like GCC always do that, instead of checking to decide whether it's redundant or not (e.g. `mov $1, (%rdi)`).  When writing asm by hand, I prefer to omit the operand-size suffix (since I'm used to Intel syntax where you look at the operands anyway.)